# Why bitoperation and multiplication is prefered here over a condition?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, bitwise-operators, micro-optimization

I found this bit operation in a source code:

```
A = 0b0001;
B = 0b0010;
C = 0b0100;

flags |= !!(flags & (A | B)) * C;
```

I can't see, why this complicated expression is used. `flags & (A | B)` filters `flags` to `A | B`. Now it's converted to `true`, if flags is set to anything, and `false` otherwise. `true * C == C` and `false * C == 0`. Is it slower to just use `flags = flags ? flags | C`?

[On GCC 7.3 it compiles to](https://godbolt.org/g/G8Un9b)

```
bitwise:
  mov eax, edi
  mov edx, edi
  or edx, 4
  test al, 3
  cmovne eax, edx
  ret

condition:
  mov eax, edi
  mov edx, 0
  or eax, 4
  test edi, edi
  cmove eax, edx
  ret
```

[Clang 6.0 also eliminate the redundant call:](https://godbolt.org/g/PP8FCn)

```
bitwise:  
  xor eax, eax
  test dil, 3
  setne al
  shl eax, 2
  or eax, edi
  ret

condition:
  mov eax, edi
  or eax, 4
  test edi, edi
  cmove eax, edi
  ret
```

Do I oversee something?

Comment: I don't see any multiplication in the question.

Comment: Whoops, got a typo in the question, thanks. Previously the text was a bit different.

Comment: How old is the code? Looks like it be an (outdated) hand-optimization for  some older compilers/hardware that didn't support conditional moves.

Comment: 10 Month. Found in the [CryEngine](https://github.com/CRYTEK/CRYENGINE/blob/11b06fac48577c0c3503b68e65926c1a84b93c0c/Code/CryEngine/RenderDll/XRenderD3D9/Vulkan/API/VKCommandList.cpp#L492)

Comment: Since it's vulkan code and vulkan won't run on old hardware, I considered this as unlikly the cause.

Comment: Funny thing is that CPUs and their abilities change over time, while hand coded C routines to get the maximum performance on those old systems are often neglected.  Let me ask another question - do these routines show up as high usage areas in any profiles you've seen?  If not, then any inefficient code is probably not worth changing.  If they do, then perhaps the coders use to these old time tricks need updating :)

Comment: The code is called once on configuring. Okay, it's called about 4-8 times in a for loop at the configure step ;)

Comment: If the code is called once, then let it be.  There are probably many more important things to tune...

Comment: I hadn't the intention to modify the code in any way, I was just interested in the intention

Comment: I looked at this again. `flags |= !!(flags & (A | B)) * C;` and `flags = flags ? flags | C : 0;` are not equivalent.

Comment: Unless you don't pick `-2147483648` it's the same, and this is not the case here ;)

Comment: I wonder if this "expression" was copied from older code, or code that was optimized for something other than x86?  I think the current code only cares about modern x86, being in a `.../XRenderD3D9/Vulkan/API/` directory.  My guess is whoever wrote that picked up this trick a while ago, and still uses it instead of a ternary operator.

Comment: And BTW, MichaelPetch is right, the equivalent ternary operator would be `flags |= (flags & (A|B)) ? C : 0`.  Or `flags = (flags & (A|B)) ? flags|C : flags`.  You left out the test with `A|B`.  I fixed your Godbolt link to use a working expression (https://godbolt.org/g/GHB7ij), and yes it compiles to better-looking asm with gcc/clang.

Comment: That's probably a Pentium 4 era optimization, when conditional jumps WRECKED performance and before compilers were (consistently) doing a great job avoiding them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You left out the test with `A|B` in your version ([spotted by MichaelPetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49241199/why-bitoperation-and-multiplication-is-prefered-here-over-a-condition#comment85489458_49241199)).  And you're zeroing `flags` instead of leaving it unmodified if the test fails.  Remember there can be other set flags in other bits which need to be unaffected by setting a flag `C` that's required/implied if either of `A` or `B` are present.  (See the comment in [the original source](https://github.com/CRYTEK/CRYENGINE/blob/11b06fac48577c0c3503b68e65926c1a84b93c0c/Code/CryEngine/RenderDll/XRenderD3D9/Vulkan/API/VKCommandList.cpp#L492) you linked: `Add TRANSFER_BIT if missing (implied)`)

And equivalent ternary operator to just replace the boolean-multiply hack would be `flags |= (flags & (A|B)) ? C : 0`.

Another way to do it is `flags = (flags & (A|B)) ? flags|C : flags`, and that compiles even better.

---

I fixed your code on Godbolt to use a correct expression, and yes it compiles to better-looking asm with gcc/clang, and MSVC.  Probably that would still be true in the context of that larger function that does more stuff with `flags`.

It looks like this version [compiles the best with gcc/clang/MSVC](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5JhYiAtgGoAYgBkAggHEAyoo4B2PgAZ1is4tMcAzABFF9DifOKee24q6lHp8wGE3dgAsXiYGNtbG6t54LASKAEaoqAwA%2BvIiDBAxcQBmzMCCAJR6ht7OeUwFJb7WdmD1kBVV3ABsihCW%2Bv48hcUAVIo1VpHOxJgEYiyKTYIR3mHzJtmKaCz4BHioLFmx0/lFJSPmMwHtM60dBr49xdbKe5WC1YOKIA8Fc07mYxPEU%2BfDeb6cKhJa7AiYP5MYgATxSJB2uX2t1KXzMAHp0e8njFBBCmOhFKgcoojIoAO6iBiEynEADWIR8GKx8UwyCYIkEmGx1VqPLwTyYihYqAAtKgAA5lY77XnuCDnLgtS5dG5ue7%2BN5GT5MxQ/SbYnULExSQqMaQAVikpBY0iM1tQ0hqvH4imEYgkei4Vlo1oIdtNZrpICsVgAdKHI1Hoy1zVJAtbbVJ7aRHVJrYIQEZSP7k6bSHBYDBEChUPIJXgGJDyJQ0OXK5CQMB9FZSDlKxDiJmIPEA6R4jFoTDpL7SHX5LICAB5FgMYd50hYeSsYBVvv4MbIDYAN0wmYXmAAHmyRBCR9bspgGH2CMQ8PJz2bmGwUPx%2BIw8PFM5AzZKNlt91FKcrEUUUAHUmAYBgM1EcRJFoJ9LUTPs00PAAOFpRRaQJFGAZBkEUfQI3aXBCBIL0fVIQYywrKtiAohDBjfXg/QDXpSGDUMI2jHjQ1ja942tB8LWzJMUzTDMsxzNiC2LCAkDrWjqwoCBFIbYgUAYWgAE4UmwtsO0hbtewXAcWCHc8xzLCdYhnOd10wZc2DXBcNzZHc9z7I8TzPKRR0vASU1ve9H0YFdXxdXgPy/eBfwlf8WEAqdDxgj14MQqQrRtFDpHQzDsMUABZbQADV/B0jwjFofRFAAJQAFTAkj1nI7hKOo%2Bs6IoqximdPgWOkvN2IQTACUbCAMoTUhhNEnL0yEKTc3tdjOPDXjeP46QrGQhcJMG5bZPgeTS065Taxo9TNJXFojGzdsGE7Yy%2BzMiy/OtcdJzs%2BcUyXFcXJ%2BvBNw8/cU285BT0kN7yFiK8bzvB83qfcLOEigQGE/b8JtTeLNkS6QgO2oRYIkOgMqysSHVyjCsJw5Bn2ARQWjDIxmeasj6La%2BgOqUjnvS4XrmJ4VihqDEM1vW6M4yminU2kSTsyWwM4y4HbxLl/ald3LtcZAQIgA%3D%3D%3D):

```
int condition(int flags) {
    flags = (flags&(A|B)) ? flags | C : flags;
    return flags;
}

; gcc/clang both emit

    mov     eax, edi
    or      eax, 4
    test    dil, 3
    cmove   eax, edi
    ret
```

And MSVC is similar, but with an `and` instead of `test`, and an extra `mov` because of the destructive `and`.

---

> Clang 6.0 also eliminate the redundant call

What `call`?  There are no function calls in this code.  Did you mean clang avoids the redundant `mov edx, edi` that gcc uses?  Yeah, gcc is dumb there.

---

#### Why would anyone write it the way they did?

Perhaps their past experience was with older compilers that didn't do a good job with the ternary operator, or with non-x86 platforms without a `cmov` and actually using a `*` operator in the source was one of the only ways to get branchless asm.

**My guess is whoever wrote that picked up this trick a while ago, and still uses it instead of a ternary operator.**  It's not a good idea, and doesn't lead to better code.

Comment: *Did you mean clang avoids the redundant mov edx, edi that gcc uses?* - Yup, sorry for the confusion.